# 240 and 504 showing up in the sphere spectrum

Tags: fourier-series, spheres

It is known that
$\pi_7(\mathbb S) = \mathbb Z/240$
and
$\pi_{11}(\mathbb S) = \mathbb Z/504$.

Is this connected to the normalized Eisenstein series,

$E_4(\tau) = 1 + 240\sum\sigma_3(n)q^n$
and
$E_6(\tau) = 1 - 504\sum\sigma_5(n)q^n$

in some direct way?

Comment: Just to be sharper, for $n \geq 9$, $\pi_{7+n}(\Bbb{S}^n) = \Bbb{Z}/240\Bbb{Z}$.  For $n \geq 13$, $\pi_{11+n}(\Bbb{S}^n) = \Bbb{Z}/504\Bbb{Z}$.  A good check is for $n \geq 17$, $\pi_{15+n}(\Bbb{S}^n) = 2 \cdot 480$, but the coefficient in question from $E_8$ is $480$.  ([reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_groups_of_spheres#Table_of_homotopy_groups))  So maybe there's something to this, but it's not exact.

Comment: Potentially relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428113/lattices-and-stable-homotopy-groups-of-spheres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this is explored in [Hopkins: Algebraic Topology and Modular Forms](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0212397.pdf) (very similar looking piece at PDF page 14, internal page 296).  Skimming (so take with a grain of salt), it looks like only "$c_4$" (a.k.a. $E_4$) and "$c_6$" ($E_6$) are used and (if there are any?) the remaining coefficients lie in some sort of span constructed from those two.